# Visual Basic Format DataGridView Column to Currency Not Working

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

If it's possible, I would like my DataGridView to format a column to currency the way an Excel spreadsheet does. For example, I want to type "7" and get "$7.00". I have found innumerable places on the internet telling me to use:

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"
Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

However, this is not working. Perhaps it is not meant to do what I think it should. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this :

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(3).ValueType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Bioukh. However, it seems "ValueType" is not a valid member of "DefaultCellStyle". The actual error I'm getting says it's "not a member of 'DataGridViewCellStyle'".